# Sum and subtract selected rows with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe and I want sum and subtract specific rows by its value. Something as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g'], 
                   'school': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'points': [28, 17, 19, 14, 23, 26, 5, 10, 15],
                   'rebounds': [5, 6, 4, 7, 14, 12, 9, 3, 9],
                   'assists': [10, 13, 7, 8, 4, 5, 8, 10, 7]})


name    school  points  rebounds    assists
0   a   A   28  5   10
1   b   A   17  6   13
2   c   A   19  4   7
3   d   B   14  7   8
4   e   B   23  14  4
5   f   B   26  12  5
6   g   C   5   9   8
7   h   C   10  3   10
8   g   C   15  9   7
```

and then I pivotted it:

```
df_1 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['points'], index='name', columns=['school'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
df_1


name    points
school      A   B   C
0   a   28.0    NaN NaN
1   b   17.0    NaN NaN
2   c   19.0    NaN NaN
3   d   NaN 14.0    NaN
4   e   NaN 23.0    NaN
5   f   NaN 26.0    NaN
6   g   NaN NaN 20.0
7   h   NaN NaN 10.0
```

Below is my expected Output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'total a + b', 'total f - e'], 
                   'A': [28, 17, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0],
                   'B': [0, 0, 0, 14, 23, 26, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                   'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 10, 0, 0]})
    name    A   B   C
0   a   28  0   0
1   b   17  0   0
2   c   19  0   0
3   d   0   14  0
4   e   0   23  0
5   f   0   26  0
6   g   0   0   20
7   h   0   0   10
8   total a + b 45  0   0
9   total f - e 0   3   0
```

So I want to create a new rows that will sum a and b from all columns and subtract f and e from all columns.
It looks easy but I don't know what to start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g'], 
                   'school': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'points': [28, 17, 19, 14, 23, 26, 5, 10, 15],
                   'rebounds': [5, 6, 4, 7, 14, 12, 9, 3, 9],
                   'assists': [10, 13, 7, 8, 4, 5, 8, 10, 7]})

df_1 = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['points'], index='name', columns=['school'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()

# put names in index
df_1.set_index("name", inplace=True)

# fill nan values with zeros
df_1.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# add new row with a + b
df_1.loc["total a + b"] = df_1.loc["a"] + df_1.loc["b"]

# add new row with a + b
df_1.loc["total f - e"] = df_1.loc["f"] - df_1.loc["e"]

df_1
```

output is

[image: Desired output]

If needed, you can reset the index and put "name" back to the columns. Also, it is possible to change the index name to "student" by writing `df_1.index.name = "student"`